# CLR trigger executing incorrectly the first time

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a CLR trigger, and the first thing it does is get the table name associated with the trigger, as follows:

```
public static void MyTrigger()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        command.CommandText = @"SELECT object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid and resource_type = 'OBJECT'";
        string tableName = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        //etc...
    }
}
```

The first time the trigger is executed, the table name returned by the above command is always `syscolpars`. If the trigger is executed again, the table name is returned correctly.

The database engine is SQL Server 2014 Express.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you trying accomplish with this code? A trigger needs to be associated with a specific table, so why not just put the table name in the trigger as a literal?

Comment: The trigger is created for every table so that's not  possible

Comment: This is completely unreliable. It arbitrarily selects one locked object in the current transaction. There is no guarantee whatsoever you'll get back the table that the trigger is associated with. Basically, you're just getting lucky it appears to work for you the second time -- it isn't "executing incorrectly the first time". I know it sucks that CLR triggers don't get the table name directly, but this is not a reliable workaround. Consider creating a CLR stored procedure instead and calling this from a regular T-SQL trigger which can pass the table name.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That won't work because I need to access the Inserted and Deleted tables.

Comment: Then I don't see any way to do this other than to give up on the idea of having one generic trigger for all tables. Your scheme trivially breaks under transactions that involve more than one table, and even those without, as you've seen (though that could be worked around by deliberately ignoring system tables in your query). The real solution is for SQL Server to pass the table name -- [unfortunately Microsoft has closed this as won't fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/768358/).